# Combining parameter errors with phylogenetic errors

Tags: error, biostatistics, pooling, phylogeny

Say I am running a phylogenetic generalised least squares (PGLS) regression with one predictor.

A model will return me a coefficient with a standard error - corrected for phylogenetic relatedness.

I also know there is uncertainty surrounding the phylogeny is use, so I run the same model multiple times using a sample of phylogenies from a MCMC generated posterior.

Is there a way to combine the standard errors from each model (which will presumably be slightly different from model to model) with the phylogenetic error from across all models?

Comment: have you considered doing your analysis in a Bayesian framework? This is easy to do using the BayesTraits program provided by Pagel and Meade here http://www.evolution.rdg.ac.uk/BayesTraitsV3.0.1/BayesTraitsV3.0.1.html. Also see this paper http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2148-12-102.pdf

Comment: BayesTraits doesn't offer the solution I want in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Why not? It integrates across a Bayesian posterior distribution of trees, which it sounds like is exactly what you have. The resulting posterior distributions of parameter estimates account for phylogenetic uncertainty.

Comment: I am aware of BayesTraits capabilities. It does not implement the particular model that I use. I would like to know how to combine these errors in a frequentist framework.

Comment: you said PGLS with one predictor, which BayesTraits most certainly does implement...

Comment: I am presenting the problem in as simple terms as possible, as per stack overflow guidelines. This is an example to highlight the different types of error i.e. phylogenetic and model error, that I want to combine.

Comment: In that case you might want to clarify the types of models you expect an answer for. If you give a specific example of a model, and you don't indicate that you want an answer for some more general class of models, then you can expect people to offer solutions for that specific example. I gave a more general solution in my answer. You also could clarify that you don't want a Bayesian solution if that is the case, since I think it is valid for someone to suggest a Bayesian approach based on what you asked (how to combine results across a posterior distribution of trees)

Comment: The question is not about models, it is about combining types of error. Uncertainty comes from two places in my example, from measurement uncertainty (the phylogeny) and model uncertainty. I would like to combine them. Changing to a Bayesian framework is one way to solve the problem, but BayesTraits will not solve my problem. I would, however, prefer to combine the errors in the model I already have, rather than begin again.

Comment: BayesTraits was just a suggestion. Again, I think you should you edit your question to clarify that you don't want a Bayesian solution. Is there a problem with the model averaging approach I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

If you're opposed to doing this in a Bayesian framework, you could fit the model for each tree in your distribution and combine the results with model averaging. See this [R tutorial](http://www.mpcm-evolution.org/practice/online-practical-material-chapter-12/chapter-12-2-dealing-phylogenetic-uncertainty-inference-across-models-considering-different-phylogenetic-hypotheses) accompanying the book chapter [Multi-model inference in comparative analyses](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-43550-2_12) by Laszlo Garamszegi and Robert Mundry.